# best way to get 1Gbps speeds with a laptop with an inbuilt ethernet card which supports only upto 100Mbps

Tags: networking, ethernet

I have a dell new inspiron laptop which supports speeds only upto 100Mbps but my network offers speed of 1Gb/s. Because of this, I get speeds of only around 40Mb/s.

and [this](http://configure.ap.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?oc=u540508in8&c=in&l=en&s=dhs&cs=indhs1&model_id=inspiron-15r-n5110) is my laptop and it does not have an express card slot. Is there any way, I can get gigabit speeds?

Comment: What model laptop do you have, precisely. Inspiron is a very wide model line and a more specific model type may give us additional possibilities regarding upgrades.

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible to upgrade your laptop's ethernet port.  The hardware is built into the laptop's motherboard and can not be upgraded or altered.  However, you can get a PCMCIA/PC card such as [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002VITFU).

Answer (score 3):

Speed USB 2.0 can theoretically reach speeds over 300Mbit/s, so a decent USB NIC would up to triple your speed. However, the rest of your system needs to be able to run on those speeds, too; USB as protocol is not very robust on constant hi-speed data transfer, so reaching the maximum theoretical limit can be hard unless all pieces of the puzzle fall into place just perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the configuration shown in the product link you provided, I think we can concur that there is no way to get true GB ethernet on your laptop. Your only external peripheral connection options are USB, and as others have stated, even USB 2 is not capable of handling the throughput of a 1Gbps ethernet connection.

You can purchase USB ethernet adapters rated for 10/100/1000 connections, but you must recognize that while they may connect at and negotiate a 1Gbps connection, they will **never** actually reach that throughput in real-life.

Here's an Amazon.com search for [USB gigabit ethernet adapters](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=aps&field-keywords=usb%20gigabit%20ethernet%20adapter).

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not possible to upgrade laptop's network speed, since most probably the network chipset is integrated into the laptop's mainboard. You can get a network PCMCIA card if your laptop sports PCMCIA port, but not USB network card, because USB is too slow for 1Gbps.

However, 1Gbps is pretty fast. Your whole laptop's I/O system needs to be able to cope with it. If your laptop is rather old, I'd say even getting the 1Gbps PCMCIA card may gain you very little in terms of network speed increase.

Comment: OP stated his laptop is new. This may also mean he doesn't have a PCMCIA slot, as those are becoming increasingly rare.

Comment: Then he can get an express card instead.

Comment: Yes my laptop is new dell inspiron 15R. It has good hardware , i5 2nd gen , 4GB ddr3 ram and 500 GB hard disc. But the network card is only disappointing